# How to treat an object I created using a class like an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, instance-methods

so I'm passing in a hash as a single argument into this class and then returning a nested array.  I have no problem converting the hash into an array, however, I can't figure out how to get the test code below to work.  I need to access the object exactly like an array while also calling instance methods on the object.  Thank you in advance guys, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Student

    attr_accessor :scores, :first_name

    def initialize(student_data)
       @student_data = student_data
       @first_name = student_data[:first_name]
       @scores = student_data[:scores]
       return @students = @student_data.to_a
    end

    def first_name
    end

    def scores
    end
end

p students[0].first_name == "Alex"
p students[0].scores.length == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your getter methods with nothing inside.

You are replacing:

```
def first_name
  return first_name
end
```

with:

```
def first_name
end
```

I am also going to assume you properly declared your students array. Something similar to:

```
students = []
students.push(Student.new({first_name: "Alex", scores: [89, 100, 93, 72, 95] }))
```

then tried:

```
p students[0].first_name == "Alex"
p students[0].scores.length == 5
```